# Why is my Obj-C, regex-based, text-wrapping method chopping off the last character?

Tags: objective-c, regex, word-wrap

I've been using regular expressions for a while, and have gotten good at using them as string-based-problem solvers. So, naturally, when I was tasked with making a word-wrap method, I approached it from a regex perspective.

The method takes a string and a `maxWidth` uint that determines where to wrap the string. The first thing the method does is break apart very long "words" ([`/(\S{##})/g`](https://regex101.com/r/zI7oR8/1), where `##` is replaced with `maxWidth`), and then it splits the string by "words" and their trailing whitespace ([`/((\S+)\s*)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/oP3uV4/2)). Then, it adds each word and its whitespace to a temporary `line` variable, unless doing so would make the line longer than `maxWidth`, in which case it first adds `line` to an array of `lines` and clears the `line` first. After this array is filled, it implodes it back into a string, with `\n` as the glue.

Strangely, this works just fine at every last part of the process... *except* when matching words, wherein **only the last word's last character is not matched.**

---

### SSCCE

```
//            Capturing Groups:  v-----1----v
//                               |v--2-v    |
#define REGEX_WORDS_AND_WHITES @"((\\S+)\\s*)"
#define REGEX_WAW_GROUP_WORD_AND_WHITE_IDX 1
#define REGEX_WAW_GROUP_WORD_IDX 2

#define REGEX_VERY_LONG_WORD_FORMAT @"(\\S{%lu})"
#define REGEX_VERY_LONG_WORD_REPLACE_TEMPLATE @"$1\n"

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];

    _wordsAndWhitesRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:REGEX_WORDS_AND_WHITES
                                                                     options:0
                                                                       error:nil];
}


+ (NSString *) wrapText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(NSUInteger)maxWidth
{
    // Initial variables
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *lines = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);
    NSMutableString __block *line = [NSMutableString new];
    NSString __block *wordStr, *wordAndWhiteStr;

    // Chop down very long words
    NSRegularExpression *veryLongWordRegex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:REGEX_VERY_LONG_WORD_FORMAT, (unsigned long)maxWidth]
                                              options:0
                                                error:nil];
    NSMutableString *mutableText = text.mutableCopy;
    [veryLongWordRegex replaceMatchesInString:mutableText options:0 range:fullRange withTemplate:REGEX_VERY_LONG_WORD_REPLACE_TEMPLATE];
    text = mutableText;

    // Split the text into its "words"
    NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult *> *wordsAndWhites = [_wordsAndWhitesRegex matchesInString:text
                                                                                    options:NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds
                                                                                      range:fullRange];
    // !!!! [text substringWithRange: (NSRange)[wordsAndWhites.lastObject rangeAtIndex:1]] outputs all but the last character of the last word !!!!

    // Go over each word and add it to a line, or add the line to the lines and clear it first if adding it to the line would overflow.
    [wordsAndWhites enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *wordAndWhiteResult, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         wordAndWhiteStr = [text substringWithRange:[wordAndWhiteResult rangeAtIndex:REGEX_WAW_GROUP_WORD_AND_WHITE_IDX]];
         wordStr = [text substringWithRange:[wordAndWhiteResult rangeAtIndex:REGEX_WAW_GROUP_WORD_IDX]];
         if (line.length + wordStr.length > maxWidth)
         {
             [lines addObject:[line trim]];
             line = [NSMutableString new];
         }
         [line appendString:wordAndWhiteStr];
     }];

    if ([line trim].length)
    {
        [lines addObject:[line trim]];
    }

    return [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}

@end
```

```
@implementation NSString (CPMobileAdditions)

- (NSString*) trim
{
    return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

@end
```

---

### Test

I tested it with the following text with a `maxWidth` of `30`:

```
This is the first line of a long paragraph with words and symbols. The line should break at whitespaces, and really long words like QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm should be broken in the middle
```

And the output is this:

```
This is the first line of a
long paragraph with words and
symbols. The line should break
at whitespaces, and really
long words like
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwer
tyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm should
be broken in the middl
```

Sadly, the last word is `middl`, when it should be `middle`. **Why is my method, specifically the line where `*wordsAndWhites` is initialized, chopping off the last character?**

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: What is `-[NSMutableString trim]`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, that's how I found the problem line I marked in my SSCCE above.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Oh, yes, sorry; that's in one of our categories. It's simply a short way of doing `[text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]`. I've added that to the SSCCE

Comment: So everything below `// !!!!` is irrelevant.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Everything below that continues to make the method work as intended, but does not contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you replace a long word, you add a character to the string, but you've saved the old length of the string; thus when you use `fullRange` in the next search, you ignore a character at the end.

If you had two over-limit words, you would lose two characters.

The range you use for the second search needs to be updated after the replacement.

Comment: So... fix by re-making the range instead of caching it at the beginning?